# Select if string is like a field in database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a form where the user types in a name and it selects everything based on that name, Ideally i'd like to be able to have it so it would select everything from the database if they typed half of the name in or just a character so everyone whose first name is dave etc.

```
try
{
    this.access_PermissionTableAdapter.FillBy(
        this.vehicleManagementDataSet.Access_Permission,   
        this.userNameToolStripTextBox.Text);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

This will select all fields when the name is spelt letter for letter but not if it is partially typed. I've been looking at the methods C# provides like contains and starswith but neither seem suitable.

Is there a way of selecting where the name is like what is typed in?

Comment: You want the [LIKE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm) clause, I can't really answer your question for you as you don't say what type of search you need i.e. starts with, ends with etc.

Comment: @James Yeah I know what i'd have to do in SQL just not in C# its a new language to me. I think startswith would be the best way to go but i don't know exactly how the method works

Comment: I thought you were accessing a stored procedure from C#. Are you looking to use something like Linq to Entities for this? The code you have shown at the minute is of little use...

Comment: No i'm not accessing stored procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_yourtable t WHERE t.columnname LIKE '%' + @searchstring + '%'
```

Comment: Took me a while to understand how I change the tableAdapter to fit my needs hence the delay in response. I'm new to c# you see and im editing someone elses code. Cheers for that

Answer (score 2):

If you have a strongly typed dataset, you can create your own custom queries (in your case, I'd call the query `StartingWith`, the SQL code of which is given by the other two responses, and it will generate a method called `FillByStartingWith`).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy(v=vs.80).aspx for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: A mixture of your help and P5Coder answer has got me there in the end cheers dude

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE COL1 LIKE '%TYPED NAME%'
```

Comment: this will prove useful to somebody but the answer from P5Coder got me what I needed, but this pointed me in the right direction cheers for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something like the `SQL`'s `LIKE` operator on c# strings then use the Contains method.

For example you have a list of strings:

```
List<string> myStringList = new List<string>();
//fill the list
```

If you want to achieve the result of Amirreza Keshavarz's or P5Coder's answer not using a database then use Linq To Objects and Contains method.

```
IEnumerable<string> result = myStringList.Where(ms => ms.Contains("typed string"));
```

If you want the strings that just starts with the typed string then use this:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = myStringList.Where(ms => ms.StartsWith("typed string"));
```

Comment: Cheers for the help i need to do it using a database but its always something i can refer back to if i ever need it

Comment: Then why don't just use LIKE operator (like others have said)?

Comment: I am doing, I'm new to C# and I've been given somebody elses code to improve I know the logic behgind it all its just getting used to how C# works and how visual studio works